# Rails - check if parent object was destroyed and is calling destroy on dependents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have the following:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :model_bs, dependent: :destroy
end

class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_a
  after_destroy :action_only_if_model_a_exists

  private

  def action_only_if_model_a_exists
    # Do things
  end
end
```

When I call `model_a.destroy`, I need to be able to determine in the `action_only_if_model_a_exists` callback in ModelB whether the associated ModelA still exists or is also about to be destroyed.

Is there a nice inbuilt Rails way of doing this or do I need to go down the path of setting a flag in ModelA in an earlier callback (e.g. `before_destroy`) which I can then check in ModelB's callback?

**Edit**

I have done multiple tests and confirmed that inside the `action_only_if_model_a_exists` callback, doing the following doesn't help:

```
> model_a.persisted?
true

> model_a.destroyed?
false

> model_a.frozen?
false
```

Comment: Are you expecting to null out the ids of model b as a strategy or actually delete the records? Also, are you worried about a few milliseconds latency or is there actually some case where you don't actually expect modela to be destroyed even though modela.destroy was called?

Comment: I'm expecting to delete the records.

Comment: And the contents of the `action_only_if_model_a_exists` method kicks off an asynchronous process which takes a few minutes to complete, and will fail if the corresponding ModelA no longer exists.

Comment: I'm confused. If you call modela.destroy, then necessarily by the time that modelb is destroyed, modela should be destroyed as well as soon as the db process completes, as you called a method on it to do exactly that. It seems like the best way would be to call modela.modelb.destroy_all from your controller, then when you have confirmed modelb's process is done, destroy modela explicitly in a second call.

Comment: The order of actions seems to be as follows:
`model_a before_destroy callback` --
`model_b before_destroy callback` --
`model_b after_destroy callback` --
`model_a after_destroy_callback`
Meaning that when model_b is being destroyed, model_a still exists in the database.

Comment: see my comment above. I would split up the process into 2 calls.

Comment: I can't add code to my controller to handle this situation as the controller is a generic location where a lot of changes happen to a dynamic set of models, and I therefore need a solution within the model itself which will handle this situation.

Comment: can you please try this one  `after_destroy :action_only_if_model_a_exists, if: -> (obj) { obj.model_a.present? }`

Comment: I would override destroy in modela and explicitly destroy modelb from there. At the end of the function call super. That guarantees that when model a.destroy is called, all the modelbs have been destroyed first, as modelb.destroy won't return until all the callbacks are finished.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `destroyed_by_association` attribute in the child to see if the object is being destroyed as part of the `dependent: :destroy` from it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest way of achieving this is by using a `before_destroy` callback in `ModelA` to call the required function on all of its associated `ModelB`s

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :model_bs, dependent: :destroy

  before_destroy { |model_a| model_a.model_bs.each { |model_b| model_b. action_only_if_model_a_exists } }
end
```

Of course, `action_only_if_model_a_exists` will need to not be private.

Also, you will want to consider how many `model_bs` any given `model_a` will likely to have, and if necessary consider using `in_batches` rather than `each`.

*UPDATE*

OK, based on your updated explanation, and my understanding now being the opposite of what it previously was, how about the following?

```
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_a
  after_destroy :action_if_not_called_from_model_a

  private

  def action_if_not_called_from_model_a
    if !caller.join.match(/model_a/)
      # Do things
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think my question must have been unclear - this is the opposite of the behaviour I'm actually after: I only want `action_only_if_model_a_exists` to trigger if `model_b.destroy` is called, not if `model_a.destroy` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a nice way to do this so I've settled on the following:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :destroying?
  has_many :model_bs, dependent: :destroy

  def destroy
    self.destroying? = true
    super
  end
end

class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_a
  after_destroy :action_only_if_model_a_exists

  private

  def action_only_if_model_a_exists
    if !model_a.destroying?
      # Do things
    end
  end
end
```